# How can I make a dragImage opaque with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

How can I make a dragImage opaque with pure JS? My code doesn't work for some reason https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-azetx8?file=index.js

Comment: [Please add the relevant code to the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1169519).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a drag image earlier

```
const dragImage = new Image();
dragImage.src = button.src;
dragImage.style.opacity = 1.0;
```

Comment: It makes the page crash https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1r844b?file=index.js